# Let $S$ is a semi-group such that $x^2y=y=yx^2$ for all $x,y$ in $S$. Is it a group and if yes, is it abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups, semigroups

Let $S$ is a semi-group such that $x^2y=y=yx^2$ for all $x,y$ in $S$. Is it a group and if yes, is it abelian?

I am asked whether $S$ **may be a group or not**. If yes, is it abelian?

I can't see how I am supposed to solve this question, given the fact that I am not given the binary operation for it. Is it multiplication?

For it to be a group, it should be closed, associative, have an identity element and an inverse element. How should I proceed to check those properties with the given property?

Comment: I am given the following options, if it gives a bit clarity:

 a) S may not be a group
 b)S must be a group if and only if S is finite.
 c)S is an abelian
 d) None of the above

Comment: Part of the goal of an exercise of this is to be able to reason about (semi)groups _abstractly_; not knowing exactly what the binary operation is is part of the point of an exercise like this.  What _can_ you prove about $S$ from what you've been given?  For instance, can you convince yourself that $S$ has an identity?

Comment: If it's a semigroup and no specific operation is given, it is assumed to be juxtaposition/multiplication and that it is associative. All you know about this operation is that it is associative, and it satisfies the identity given.

Comment: "$S$ may not be a group" is ambiguous in English. It could mean either that it is definitely not a group or that it is possibly not a group.

Comment: I would guess that the intended answer is that $S$ is an abelian group, which is essentially proved in Berci's answer, but you need the extra assumption that $S$ is nonemtpy.

Answer (score 5):

We are given that $S$ is a semigroup: so it's already equipped with an associative operation.

It becomes a group if we show existence of the unit and inverse elements.

Fix an arbitrary $x\in S$, and let  $e:=x^2$. By the conditions, we have $ey=y=ye$ for all $y\in S$, so $e$ is a unit element, and as such it's unique.
(Alternatively, we have $u^2 =u^2v^2 =v^2$ when applying the conditions once with $x=u, y=v^2$ and once with $x=v, y=u^2$.) 
Consequently, $x^2=e$ for *every* $x\in S$, and thus $x^{-1}$ exists and $x^{-1}=x$.

Finally, it's also Abelian, because $xyxy=(xy)^2=e=x^2y^2 =xxyy\implies yx=xy$.

Comment: But $S$ could be empty, in which case it would not be a group

Comment: Well, yes, indeed, we need to assume $S$ is nonempty.